# Refreshing an expired access token for specific user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

The application which I am building maps a user_id to multiple facebook accounts. I have access tokens for each of these mapped accounts and everything works nicely. There is a problem, though, when one of these access tokens expires but the user is logged in to Facebook as a different user than the one to whom the expired access token belongs.

I read all there is about obtaining a new access token for the currently logged in user but I found nothing about the case when the user whose access token expired is not logged in to Facebook.

I would appreciate your thoughts and possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Users can't have multiple Facebook accounts, so that part of your question doesn't entirely make sense, but in general, if an access token expires you need the user to come back to your app and go through the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) flow again, which will give you a new access token for that user

Comment: Thanks Igy. My application maps users (local users, not facebook) to facebook accounts. So my A user can have fb1 and fb2 Facebook accounts mapped to it. That's what I meant.

Comment: I still don't quite understand how that doesn't amount to people having multiple Facebook accounts, but regardless - once the token expires they need to go through the authentication flow again

Comment: Well, I guess that what you really mean when saying that people cannot have multiple Facebook accounts is that once user A logs out from account fb1 and logs back to Facebook using account fb2 the OAuth2 access token for fb1 automatically becomes invalid. But even then, since I have the user ids for both fb1 and fb2, can I force re-authentication on fb1? I know I can log out the currently logged in user... hmm, perhaps it would work this way...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to get an updated access token would be to go through the whole authentication process again from the initial login screen.

Depending on the technology with which you're building your application, the only way I can imagine you'd handle logging in to a Facebook account without logging out of an existing one is to set up parallel instances of web browsers, so long as they don't share things like cookies.